# redirect http to https except in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I've moved my node.js app to https. I setup https via nginx reverse proxy. I have one problem though, when I enter example.com it doesn't redirect to https://example.com. so I try to write this code in my app.js

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.host.indexOf('localhost') > -1 || req.secure) {
    return next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+req.url);
  }
});
```

it doesn't work when I redeploy, any clue?

Comment: Error logs? They tend to be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

if you do with app express module and you want to get with '/' response then simple case check following terms:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.host.indexOf('localhost') > -1 || req.secure) {
    return next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('https://google.com');
  }
});
```

check your code with it. it's completely running then if you want to listen secure server then createServer with exress with secure manner like

```
var secureServer = require('https').createServer(httpsOptions, app);
```

httpsOptions data is your certificate file and key file